# Asp.net mvc5 value dosen't save to the database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Right now  I have a MVC5 project that looks like this when creating a post:
[image]

So I do get a Drop down lsit for both GameId and NextGame which is how I want it.
How ever when creating this post only 'GameId' gets saved to the database.
While the NextGame Tab would be left at null. 
Any idea on how I would go a head and fix this?

**This is my Post model**

```
   public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    //URL
    [Display(Name = "URL")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    //User
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    //Game
    [Display(Name = "Game")]
    public int GameId { get; set; }

    public string NextGame { get; set; }

    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    //Time
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            if (_date == null || _date.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                return _date = DateTime.Now;
            }
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
        }
    }
```

**And here is my PostModelCreate method**

```
        // GET: Posts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title");
        ViewBag.NextGame = new SelectList(db.Games, "NextGame", "Title");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Posts/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Url,GameId,NextGame,Date")] Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title", post.GameId);
        ViewBag.NextGame = new SelectList(db.Games, "NextGame", "Title", post.NextGame);

        return View(post);
    }
```

And this is my view where I create the dropdown lists

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GameId, "GameId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GameId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NextGame, "NextGame", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("NextGame", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NextGame, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show the view code for the 2 dropdownlists

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry for that, updated the post with my view.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in post action and see if `NextGame` is being posted or not?

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `post.NextGame` is null in the controller when you submit?

Comment: @StephenMuecke When creating this it will save NextGame null in my Database. And yes, post.NextGame is null in the controller

Comment: From your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112062/populate-a-mvc5-list) did not have a property `string NextGame` (only `int GameId` and `string Title`) - have you changed to add a new property?

Comment: Yes. On my Game I added a property called NextGame.
Because if I did not have that property it did complain it could not find 'NextGame' property on my Game Model

Comment: `NextGame` I think should be an `int` after looking at `GameId` property. By the way what is the column type back at SQL?

Comment: Seems a strange way to do it - why not make the property `public int NextGame` and use the same `SelectList` (i.e use the `GameId` property).

Comment: Best guess is that the value of property `NextGame ` is null when you use `new SelectList(db.Games, "NextGame", "Title");` so its generating options with `<option value>Battlefield 2</option>` - check the html your generating

Comment: Seems a strange way to do it - why not make the property public int NextGame and use the same SelectList (i.e use the GameId property).

Might be a strange way to do it, but that's how I though  I would do it, still learning I'll try to redo it with that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your game Table is set up but this may help.

In your Model Change NextGame  to NextGame Id

```
public class Game
{
    [Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string GameDisc { get; set; }

    public int GameRating { get; set; }


}
public class PostInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }

    //URL
    [Display(Name = "URL")]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    //User
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    //Game
    [Display(Name = "Game")]
    public virtual ICollection<Game> GameId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Game> NextGameID { get; set; }
//Or use this
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
public virtual Game NextGameID { get; set; }

    //Time
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            if (_date == null || _date.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                return _date = DateTime.Now;
            }
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
        }
    }
}
```

In your Controller change The following

```
ViewBag.NextGame = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title", post.NextGame);


public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Url,GameId,NextGameId,Date")] Post post)

ViewBag.NextGameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title", post.NextGameId);
```

Controller;

```
// GET: Posts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title");
        ViewBag.NextGameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Posts/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Url,GameId,NextGameId,Date")] Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title", post.GameId);
        ViewBag.NextGameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "Title", post.NextGameId);

        return View(post);
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GameId, "GameId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GameId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NextGameId, "NextGame", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("NextGameId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NextGameId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply that is kinda how I redid the whole thing except I did not name it NextGameId only NextGame. And it seems to work. How ever when showing the model I go to modelItem => item.NextGame and this will only show the INT and not the title.

While for my GameID I can do this. modelItem => item.Game.Title and it will show the title


Of course I could add another property to my GameModel called NextGame but that would mean when I add a new game I have to add a Title and a NextGame which seems to be doubled the work.

Comment: Will the game be added to your game database, if so you will only be showing the ID for the game displaying the title.

Comment: Is there any good way to fix this? 
Except if I add another property called NextGame on my GameModel. But that seems to be doubled the work.

Comment: I would add GameId and NextGameId to the user table and that way you just reference the game table to display the titles for that user, and or add titles to the game table,

Comment: Just chaninge it ID would hat even change anything?

Comment: Yes if the model does not have the second NextGame in the post it can not post it to the database.